# error when moving to another page next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm receiving this error when moving to another page in next js

> 1 of 3 unhandled errors
>
> Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'pagenum')
>
> Source
> pages\dpt[dptid]\rewayat[rewid][subrewid]\surah[surahid]\p[pid].js
> (89:36) @ Page
>
> 87 | imag =
> `/image/${dptid}/${rewid}/${subrewid}/${surahid}/${pid}.png`;   88 |
>
> > 89 | pagenum = surahs[`surah${surahid}`].pagenum;
> > |                                    ^   90 | console.log(pagenum);   91 | page = surahs[`surah${surahid}`].page;
> > 92 |

my code :

```
  const router = useRouter()
  const pid = router.query.pid;
  const rewid = router.query.rewid;
  const dptid = router.query.dptid;
  const subrewid = router.query.subrewid
  const surahid = router.query.surahid


  
  let imag;
  let aud;
  
  
  let pagenum;
  let page;
  let surahs = {};

   surahs = {
    surah1: {
      page : "1",
      pagenum: "1",
      surahname: "الفاتحة",
  },
  surah2: {
    page : 2,
      pagenum: 3,
      surahname: "البقرة",
      
  },
  surah19: {
      page : "305",
      pagenum: "1",
      surahname: "مريم",
      
  }

}
imag = `/image/${dptid}/${rewid}/${subrewid}/${surahid}/${pid}.png`;
 
pagenum = surahs[`surah${surahid}`].pagenum;
console.log(pagenum);
page = surahs[`surah${surahid}`].page;

aud = `/sound/${rewid}/${subrewid}/19/${pid}.mp3`;
```

```
 <Drawer  className='font-el-messiri text-center' title="اختر الصفحه" placement="bottom" height={"500px"}  width={"300px"} size="default" onClose={onClose1} open={open1}>
        <div className=' flex flex-col justify-center items-center'>
         
       {pages}
       

</div>
        
      </Drawer>
```

i think it is something wrong with const surahs

im expecting the navbar moves to any page without this error

Comment: Have you checked the value of `surah${surahid}`, see if that key is present in the `surahs` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like **surahs[`surah${surahid}`]** returning null. make sure `surahid` has a matching value in the object or add the optional operator

```
pagenum = surahs[`surah${surahid}`]?.pagenum;
```